# Passing a variable as an argument using mailcmd in voicemail.conf

Tags: asterisk

In my voicemail.conf file, I have a line that looks like this:

mailcmd=php /path/to/file.php 1234

In this case, "1234", which is passed to file.php just fine, is an extension, but frankly, I don't care exactly *what* gets passed as long as it's something I can use to identify the inbox where the voicemail will get stored.  Because of that, I really need to be able to pass it a variable, like this:

mailcmd=php /path/to/file.php "${VM_NAME}"

When I do that, I get an empty argument in my PHP file.  I've tried a few different channel variables, but I've never gotten anything to work unless the value is hard-coded.

Is it possible to do what I want to do here, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, it's not possible.  Asterisk's variables aren't available to voicemail.conf at the point where it's using mailcmd.

As an alternative, I needed to use STDIN inside my PHP script to glean the email header info, which could be configured to get me the extension relatively easily.

Comment: No, you are wrong. There is externnotify command which have message and extension. So it is possible.

Comment: I agree that externnotify can be used, but I was specifically looking to use mailcmd in this instance.

Comment: how do you get the audio pathfile?

Answer (score 0):

From voicemail.sample.conf

```
externnotify

Want to run an external program whenever a caller leaves a voice mail message for a user? This is where the externnotify command comes in handy. Externnotify takes a string value which is the command line you want to execute when the caller finishes leaving a message.
Note: see an example of an external notification script here.
Note: This command will also run after a person who has logged into a mailbox exits the VoiceMailMain() application. (Remark: This seems not to be the case for Asterisk 1.2.x)

The way it works is basically any time that somebody leaves a voicemail on the system (regardless of mailbox number), the command specified for externnotify is run with the arguments (in this order): context, extension, new voicemails, old voicemails and urgent voicemails. These arguments are passed to the program that you set in the externnotify variable.
```

Sample is [here](http://mikecathey.com/code/vmnotify/)